# Can I call an ant script from another ant script? What have I to do?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I am pretty new in Ant (I came from Maven) and I have a doubt if I can do the following operation using Ant.

I have 5 projects in my Eclipse workspace. One of this project is the main project, the others are dependencies of the main project.

In this time I have a single big (and confusing) ant project in the main project that do the following operation:

1) Compile dependencies project and create the jars of all these dependencies project and copy these jar into a directory named lib that is into the main project

2) Compile and create the jar file for the main project (that use the others created jar)

This version of the ant script is not appreciated by my boss because it appears to be a bit 'confusing and he ask to me to do the following refactor of ant script:

1) **Create an ant script for each dependencies project**. This script compile the related project and create the related jar into a directory named **Release** that is into the current project (this is pretty simple).

2) **Create an ant script for the main project that call all the ant script for each dependencies project**

Can I do this thing? If it is possible what have I to do to call an ant script from another ant script?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 5):

I use the same method to compile all my projects.

use this command

```
<ant antfile="../<project-dir>/build.xml" dir="../<project-dir>" />
```

Comment: mmm what is "../pippo/build.xml" ? the ant script for another project in the workspace (project named "pippo")? or what? TNX

Comment: yes pippo is the name of the folder of the project where you want to lanch the build.xml! sorry for the bad name i use :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use the import function so your current build script knows where the other build script is.  Then you should be able to call operations on the other script.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html